# Using a variable on sqlalchemy query filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

its possible to use variables on filters?

My actual code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


location = 'localhost'
engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://xxx:xxx@xxx/xxx'.format(location)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
connection = engine.connect()
session = session(bind=connection)
metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()

class Services(Base):
    """
    Service details on database
    """
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    color= Column(String)
    shape= Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.shape
```

This works:

```
for c in session.query(Services).filter(Services.name.in_(['blue','red'])):
    print(c)
```

result:

```
    circle, square
```

But using avariable, returns:

```
services = ('blue','red')
for c in session.query(Services).filter(Services.name.in_([services])):
    print(c)
```

result:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your last sample code is not actually *using* `services`. What is the actual code you are using?

Comment: @MartijnPieters hi, what you mean?

Comment: Your last sample of code uses the exact same `for` loop as the other sample. `services` is not used in that loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Ah, thanks for pointing that out, bad copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`services` is *already* a sequence, no need to wrap it in a list:

```
for c in session.query(Services).filter(Services.name.in_(services)):
```

Comment: Oh geez... cant believe it was that... Martijin, i cant count the times you saved me from overnight bad code development. Thanks again!